# Angular cli CKEditor path not found

Tags: angular, ckeditor, angular-cli

I'm trying to include the CKEditor package that I downloaded from the official website inside the `angular-cli.json` file but I'm getting this error: (file not found)

> GET http://localhost:4200/ckeditor/core/loader.js

**angular-cli.json -**

```
 "scripts": [
    "vendor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"
  ],
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: What don't you import the script in your html page like this : `<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/full/ckeditor.js"></script>` ?

Comment: Because the office2013 skin is not there.